# Bitmap - Base64 String - Bitmap conversion android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, base64

I am encoding an image in the following way and store it in my database:

```
 public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Now I am trying to decode it in the following way and display it in an `ImageView` :

```
  try{
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getBytes());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

However the `ImageView` remains blank and the image is not displayed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try decoding the string first from Base64.

```
 public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
 }
```

In you case:

```
 try{
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedByte);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying I should do this instead of my try/catch block or in addition to it?

Comment: It works when I simply replace the try catch with the code you provided :)